# django i can't see my form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I don't understand why I can't see my form.

I would like to create a form with a drop down menu with display_name of rider model as the choices.

my models.py:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank= True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank= True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank= True)
    birth = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    place_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank= True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank= True)
    height = models.FloatField(default = 0.0 ,blank= True)
    weight = models.FloatField(default = 0.0 ,blank= True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length = 256, blank= True)
    team_code = models.CharField(max_length = 256, blank= True)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name
```

my form.py:

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
   riders =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Rider.objects.all(),to_field_name="display_name")
   class Meta:
      model = Rider
      fields = ('display_name',)
```

my view.py:

```
class ScoreView(TemplateView):
    form_class = ScoreForm
    model=Rider
    template_name = 'blog/score.html'
```

my score.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<h1>Score page</h1>
<form method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" name="button">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Alasdair i tried but i don't get changes :(

Comment: Your operating system doesn't come with screenshot technology? :) Even better: just open up "show source" and copy paste the relevant html. From the screenshot it's just about possible that there actually is a `<form>` there. But it only contains the hidden csrf field.

Comment: sry I had forgotten the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically include the form in the template context, subclass `FormView` instead of `TemplateView`. The form view will automatically create a form instance from `form_class` and insert it into the template context where you can render it by using the tag `{{ form }}`.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class ScoreView(FormView):
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views